# Same thread is able to execute on same objects two synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

As I Know only one thread can execute on a synchronize method on same block but in below producer consumer problem I am able to run both the methods.

**Sample Code**

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class VIV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Number no = new Number();

        //Same Object is passed
        Even ev = new Even(no, 10);
        Odd od = new Odd(no, 10);

        Thread oddThraed = new Thread(od,"ODD");
        oddThraed.start();

        Thread evenThraed = new Thread(ev,"Even");
        evenThraed.start();
    }
}

class Number {

    int no;
    boolean flag=false;

    public synchronized int getEvenNo() {
        System.out.println("In Even Method");
        // wait block so no other thread can enter on same object synchronized method
        try{
            wait();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        if(!flag) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }   

        no=no+1;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+no);
        flag=false;
        notify();
        return no;
    }

    public synchronized int getOddNo() {
        System.out.println("In ODD Method");
        // wait block so no other thread can enter on same object synchronized method
        try{
            wait();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        if(flag) {
            try{
               wait();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }   
        no = no+1;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+no);
        flag=true;
        notify();
        return no;
    }

}

class Even implements Runnable {
    Number num;
    int noOfTime;

    Even(Number no, int noOfTime) {
        this.num=no;
        this.noOfTime=noOfTime;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<noOfTime;i++) {
            num.getEvenNo();
        }   
    }
}

class Odd  implements Runnable {

    Number num;
    int noOfTime;

    Odd(Number no, int noOfTime) {
        this.num=no;
        this.noOfTime=noOfTime;
    }   

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<noOfTime;i++) {
            num.getOddNo();
        }   
    }
}
```

**OutPut** :

1. In ODD Method
2. In Even Method

As Only one Number object is created and passed to other classes which are invoking on its two different synchronized  methods. Both methods are printing the message after that waiting .

Comment: "only one thread can execute on a synchronize method on same block" it is not complete sentence. "only one thread can execute on a synchronize method on same block at same time". This mean that they will be execute one after another.

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve in the above code ? Will you elaborate more ?

Comment: @OO7 I'm pretty sure OP is trying to test how synchronization works, by setting up two synchronized methods and checking that execution of one will block execution of the other; and he's finding that actually both methods can be executed simultaneously. The problem is the `wait()` calls, which release the lock.

Comment: This is a classical deadlock. To solve it, we need some more explanation. What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It's not a deadlock. If it were a deadlock, he would be getting no output; but in fact he's getting both methods executing at the same time. That is the behaviour he is looking to explain. And the synchronization isn't working because of the `wait()` calls, which release the lock.

Comment: @chiastic-security Sorry to say that ... But you are wrong. Look at the `run` methods. They try to call the synchronized methods 10 times (the argument 10 was passed into the constructor). But the output happens only once, and then is dead-locked, which happens because of the `wait` calls! As the first `wait` call releases the lock, the other thread can enter the synchronized block - until the `wait` call. That also releases the lock, and both threads now are waiting (because no thread reaches the `notify` call)!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes, you're right, I'd missed that it was being run 10 times. We are both right, in fact: the `wait()` is why the two `synchronized` methods can both be entered simultaneously; but it's also why they then both block and there's no more output.

Comment: @chiastic-security Exactly! The interesting point here is: Both threads are dead-locked, but all locks are released. Fine.

Comment: I think OP is trying to call `ODD` & `EVEN` alternatively. M I right @chiastic-security & @Seelenvirtuose. ?

Comment: @OO7 Well, maybe alternately, but certainly not simultaneously. It wouldn't be against the sync principles if they weren't in strict alternation, though.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that both methods get executed at the same time is that the `wait()` method **releases the lock**. Once your `synchronized` method calls `wait()`, the lock is given back, and another thread can invoke another `synchronized` method on the same object. Don't call `wait()` inside a `synchronized` method in this way!

The `wait()` calls are also the reason that you're getting deadlock. This is what is happening:

1. The `odd` method acquires the lock and starts executing.
2. The `odd` method prints its first message.
3. The `odd` method invokes `wait()`, which releases the lock and waits to be notified.
4. The `even` method can now acquire the lock that's been released.
5. The `even` method prints its first message.
6. The `even` method invokes `wait()`, which releases the lock and waits to be notified.

By this point, you're in the middle of both `synchronized` methods (because `wait()` releases the lock), and you're deadlocked (because both methods are waiting).

Don't call `wait()` unless you're quite sure that's what you need. If your `wait()` is there just to keep it waiting to see if the synchronization can be broken, you might try `Thread.sleep()` instead, which will pause without releasing any locks. Usually it's enough to declare the relevant methods or blocks as `synchronized` without needing any `wait` / `notify`.

(By the way, it's not a good idea to have a class called `Number`, because this is a standard JDK class. It's the superclass of `Double`, `Integer`, and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are trying to achieve this kind of thing, if you are trying to call **EVEN & ODD alternatively**, then I have modified your code for the same. Have a look at below code :-

```
public class VIV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        TestNumber no = new TestNumber();
        // Same Object is passed
        Even ev = new Even(no, 10);
        Odd od = new Odd(no, 10);

        Thread oddThraed = new Thread(od, "ODD");
        oddThraed.start();

        Thread evenThraed = new Thread(ev, "Even");
        evenThraed.start();
    }
}

class TestNumber {

    int     no;
    boolean flag    = false;

    public synchronized int getEvenNo() {
        System.out.println("In Even Method");
        // wait block so no other thread can enter on same object synchronized
        // method

        no = no + 1;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + no);
        flag = false;
        notify();

        try {
            wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        if (!flag) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        return no;
    }

    public synchronized int getOddNo() {
        System.out.println("In ODD Method");
        no = no + 1;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + no);
        flag = true;
        notify();
        // wait block so no other thread can enter on same object synchronized
        // method
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        if (flag) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        return no;
    }
}

class Even implements Runnable {
    TestNumber  num;
    int     noOfTime;

    Even(TestNumber no, int noOfTime) {
        this.num = no;
        this.noOfTime = noOfTime;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTime; i++) {
            num.getEvenNo();
        }
    }
}

class Odd implements Runnable {

    TestNumber  num;
    int     noOfTime;

    Odd(TestNumber no, int noOfTime) {
        this.num = no;
        this.noOfTime = noOfTime;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfTime; i++) {
            num.getOddNo();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :** As suggested by @chiastic-security **Number** is already defined in JDK, I have renamed it to **TestNumber** in this code.

**Output :**

```
In ODD Method
ODD:1
In Even Method
Even:2
In ODD Method
ODD:3
In Even Method
Even:4
In ODD Method
ODD:5
In Even Method
Even:6
In ODD Method
ODD:7
In Even Method
Even:8
In ODD Method
ODD:9
In Even Method
Even:10
In ODD Method
ODD:11
In Even Method
Even:12
In ODD Method
ODD:13
In Even Method
Even:14
In ODD Method
ODD:15
In Even Method
Even:16
In ODD Method
ODD:17
In Even Method
Even:18
In ODD Method
ODD:19
In Even Method
Even:20
```