# Java: Multi Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

/* Whats went wrong here, every time producer only executing and consumer not consuming anything. Please explain me what went wrong in this code.

My Expected Result : Producer Produce 1 item then Consumer has to consume that item */

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConsumerAndProducerMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        int MAX_SIZE = 10;
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
        final Producer producer = new Producer(MAX_SIZE, list);
        final Consumer consumer = new Consumer(MAX_SIZE, list);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    producer.producer();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Producer : Exception occured because of multi threading...");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    consumer.consumer();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Consumer : Exception occured because of multi threading...");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("Program terminated..");
    }
}

class Producer {
    int size;
    ArrayList<Integer> list;
    public Producer(int size, ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.list = list;
    }
    public void producer() throws InterruptedException{
        int value = 0;
        while(true){
            synchronized (this)
            {
                if(list.size() == size){
                    System.out.println("Producer : List is full");
                    wait();
                }else{
                    list.add(++value);
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    notify();
                    System.out.println("Value produce by the producer : "+value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer {
    int size;
    ArrayList<Integer> list;
    public Consumer(int size, ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.list = list;
    }
    public void consumer() throws InterruptedException{
        while(true){
            synchronized (this)
            {
                if(list.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("Consumer : List is empty");
                    wait();
                }else{
                    int removedItem = list.remove(list.size());
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    notify();
                    System.out.println("Value consumed by the consumer : "+removedItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be resolved by reading some itntroductory material on Java concurrency. Each of your threads is using its own lock, so no coordination occurs.

Comment: The point that Marko is making, is that for `wait` `notify` to work, they must notify / wait on the same object. However, each object is locking on itself instead of a common object.

Comment: Similar to this [Same thread is able to execute on same objects two synchronized methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361367/same-thread-is-able-to-execute-on-same-objects-two-synchronized-methods/26362523#26362523)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to sycnhronize, wait and notify for the list you use, not for objects Producer and Consumer you do.

Producer:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> list;
// ...
synchronized (list) {
  if (list.size() == size) {
    System.out.println("Producer : List is full");
    list.wait();
  } else {
    list.add(++value);
    Thread.sleep(200);
    list.notify();
    System.out.println("Value produce by the producer : " + value);
  }
}
```

Consumer:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> list;
// ...
synchronized (list) {
  if (list.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Consumer : List is empty");
    list.wait();
  } else {
    int removedItem = list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    Thread.sleep(200);
    list.notify();
    System.out.println("Value consumed by the consumer : " + removedItem);
  }
}
```

The output is look like:

```
Value produce by the producer : 1
Value produce by the producer : 2
Value produce by the producer : 3
Value produce by the producer : 4
Value produce by the producer : 5
Value produce by the producer : 6
Value produce by the producer : 7
Value produce by the producer : 8
Value produce by the producer : 9
Value produce by the producer : 10
Producer : List is full
Value consumed by the consumer : 10
Value consumed by the consumer : 9
Value consumed by the consumer : 8
...
```

For your expected result (Producer produce 1 item then Consumer has to consume that item) you need to change logic with order of wait and notify: Producer add item, notify, then wait for Consumer notify, Consumer wait for Producer notify, consume 1 item then wait for Producer notify again.

Comment: "...you need to sycnhronize, wait and notify for the list..."  Actually, the threads can use any object for synchronization.  It doesn't have to be the list that they share.  Using the list is convenient because they already share it, but in large, complex systems it often makes sense to synchronize on a different object than the one that holds the data.

Comment: Hi,

Tried to call notify and wait method on list, whenever list.wait() method called in Producer i am getting below error and even increased arraylist size 10 to 20, still getting the same error. 

    `Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
 at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:387)
 at Consumer.consumer(ConsumerAndProducerMain.java:112)
 at   ConsumerAndProducerMain$2.run(ConsumerAndProducerMain.java:41)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)`

Comment: Got the problem, actually i am getting indexoutofbound exception because of `list.remove(list.size())` but it suppose to be `list.remove(list.size()-1)`

Thanks for the solution whoever helped me in this.